# How to avoid caching when values are null?

Tags: caching, guava

I am using Guava to cache hot data. When the data does not exist in the cache, I have to get it from database:

```
public final static LoadingCache<ObjectId, User> UID2UCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        //.maximumSize(2000)
        .weakKeys()
        .weakValues()
        .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build(
        new CacheLoader<ObjectId, User>() {
            @Override
            public User load(ObjectId k) throws Exception {
                User u = DataLoader.datastore.find(User.class).field("_id").equal(k).get();
                return u;
            }
        });
```

My problem is when the data does not exists in database, I want it to return `null` and to not do any caching. But Guava saves `null` with the key in the cache and throws an exception when I get it:

> com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader$InvalidCacheLoadException:
>   CacheLoader returned null for key shisoft.

How do we avoid caching `null` values?

Comment: Note that caching the nulls might save you a lot of database accesses, of course, depending on your access pattern. Thus I wouldn't refuse to cache them without some thoughts.

Comment: guava will NOT save null with key in the cache but throw exception

Comment: an interesting tidbit: if you happen to use RuntimeExcpetions for this, guava repackages these into com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException ;-|

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Just throw some Exception if user is not found and catch it in client code while using [`get(key)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#get%28K%29) method.

```
new CacheLoader<ObjectId, User>() {
    @Override
    public User load(ObjectId k) throws Exception {
        User u = DataLoader.datastore.find(User.class).field("_id").equal(k).get();
        if (u != null) {
             return u;
        } else {
             throw new UserNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

From [`CacheLoader.load(K)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#load%28K%29) Javadoc:

> ```
> Returns:  
>   the value associated with key; must not be null  
> Throws:  
>   Exception - if unable to load the result
> ```

Answering your doubts about caching null values:

> Returns the value associated with key in this cache, first loading
>   that value if necessary. **No observable state associated with this
>   cache is modified until loading completes**.

*(from [`LoadingCache.get(K)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#get%28K%29) Javadoc)*

If you throw an exception, load is not considered as complete, so no new value is cached.

**EDIT**:

Note that in [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), which is sort of Guava cache 2.0 and "provides an in-memory cache using a Google Guava inspired API" you [*can* return `null` from `load` method](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/2.6.2/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/CacheLoader.html#load-K-):

> ```
>  Returns:
>    the value associated with key or null if not found
> ```

If you may consider migrating, your data loader could freely return when user is not found.

Comment: The get() method only throws ExecutionException for all checked exception. So how the client can differentiate from actual exceptions that are thrown because of an error and the UserNotFoundException in this example? Generally speaking a well designed api should not force its clients to use exception to control ordinary workflow.

Comment: @Arash You can catch `ExecutionException` and its cause would be `UserNotFoundException` in that case (of course you should do an `instanceof` check after `.getCause()` to make sure it was not another checked exception). Or you can use `getUnckecked` (if you don't fancy checked exceptions) or `getIfPresent` if `get` is not what you need.

Comment: This violates Effective Java 69: Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions.

Comment: @AdamBliss I beg to differ, it's exceptional case in terms of Guava's `LoadingCache` contract - you were "unable to load result" and thus throw exception. 

Also, item 55 (regarding returning `Optional`) states that "In summary, if you find yourself writing a method that can’t always return a value (...) for performance-critical methods, it may be better to return a null or throw an exception."

Comment: @Xaerxess I agree that "unable to load result" is exceptional from the Cache's perspective. But "no entry in DB" is not exceptional from the Loader's perspective, and that's what's throwing. What this really means is that the LoadingCache contract is not quite suitable for this use case. One could implement a "PartialCache<T>" atop a LoadingCache<Optional<T>>, but I think doing so with invalidate() would be better than throw/catch.

Comment: @AdamBliss Can't argue with Guava cache design decisions, especially that [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), its successor, [allows returning `null` as "value-not-found" from `CacheLoader#load(K)`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/2.6.2/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/CacheLoader.html#load-K-). I've edited my answer and mentioned Caffeine cache.

Comment: This will not work now as null values now throwing com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException

Comment: @quintin It hasn't changed IMO, it's always been wrapping any runtime exceptions with `UncheckedExecutionException`, but the cause should be `UserNotFoundException` for the answer above.

Comment: @Xaerxess  I found this while debugging with null value.

Comment: @quintin Yes, I was not talking about OP's solution with returning nulls, which is wrong, but my answer. In that case it was always this way, as stated in `get` / `getUnchecked` javadoc it throws "`UncheckedExecutionException` - if an unchecked exception was thrown while loading the value". The cause would be `UserNotFoundException `.

Answer (score 59):

Simple solution: use `com.google.common.base.Optional<User>` instead of `User` as value.

```
public final static LoadingCache<ObjectId, Optional<User>> UID2UCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        ...
        .build(
        new CacheLoader<ObjectId, Optional<User>>() {
            @Override
            public Optional<User> load(ObjectId k) throws Exception {
                return Optional.fromNullable(DataLoader.datastore.find(User.class).field("_id").equal(k).get());
            }
        });
```

EDIT: I think @Xaerxess' answer is better.

Comment: Thechnically it will cache "null" values (i.e. `Optional.absent()` objects), so it does not avoid caching null values as OP wanted, but the cost isn't big.

Comment: Doesn't matter. I had a slightly different problem, and your solution helped. ;)

Comment: I think this answer should be removed. Not because it is not ok for certain situations - but it might confuse readers as IT CACHES ABSENT VALUES (as opposed to the requirements in the question).

Comment: when using the `cache.get( key )`, in case `Optional.absent` is returned, you can just `cache.invalidate( key )`  to make sure `Optional.absent` is only there for the life of the `get` call. and then poof.. it's gone.

Comment: Storing Optional.absent() is very useful for cases where you want to avoid doing the re-loading of the absent values all the time, but rather with the same expiry timeframe as the other cached values, which works nicely with Optional!

Answer (score 5):

Faced the same issue, cause missing values in the source was part of the normal workflow. Haven't found anything better than to write some code myself using `getIfPresent`, `get` and `put` methods. See the method below, where `local` is `Cache<Object, Object>`:

```
private <K, V> V getFromLocalCache(K key, Supplier<V> fallback) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    V s = (V) local.getIfPresent(key);
    if (s != null) {
        return s;
    } else {
        V value = fallback.get();
        if (value != null) {
            local.put(key, value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that many parallel calls of the same key can be done to `fallback.get()`, causing to calculate the same value. There are cases where this can be quite heavy.

Comment: Yes. This is the answer. The Guava LoadingCache is worthless because of its poor null handling.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to cache some NULL values, you could use other staff which namely behave as NULL.

And before give the solution, I would suggest you not to expose LoadingCache to outside. Instead, you should use method to restrict the scope of Cache.

For example, you could use `LoadingCache<ObjectId, List<User>>` as return type. And then, you could return empty list when you could'n retrieve values from database. You could use -1 as Integer or Long **NULL** value, you could use "" as String **NULL** value, and so on. After this, you should provide a method to handler the NULL value.

```
when(value equals NULL(-1|"")){
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Nope, if you want this, use the java.util.Optional class. See also @卢声远 Shengyuan Lu' answer + comments.

Answer (score 0):

I use the getIfPresent

```
@Test
    public void cache() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("3-------" + totalCache.get("k2"));
        System.out.println("4-------" + totalCache.getIfPresent("k3"));
    }



    private LoadingCache<String, Date> totalCache = CacheBuilder
            .newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(500)
            .refreshAfterWrite(6, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .build(new CacheLoader<String, Date>() {
                @Override
                @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
                public Date load(String key) {
                    Map<String, Date> map = ImmutableMap.of("k1", new Date(), "k2", new Date());
                    return map.get(key);
                }
            });
```