# How to let missing entries expire more quickly in Guava

Tags: java, caching, guava

I have a Java service that translates a String key to a Long id, through a database lookup.  I'm wrapping it in a Guava Cache to reduce database queries.  The mapping from key to id doesn't change once it's set, so I can use a long expire time for existing keys.  But there is a timing issue (not in Guava but in my app) where someone might lookup the id for a key before it is in the database.  I do not want to cache this "missing" mapping for very long.  I do want to cache it though, to avoid a rush of queries for the same missing key.

I read this question: [Handle null value ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379071/how-to-avoid-caching-when-values-are-null), and from there I cobbled together a solution with 2 caches.  I have a "missing keys" cache, which I let expire more quickly and it has no auto-load function.  I check this cache first, and if I find something there I know it's a missing key.  Otherwise, I try the "real" cache, catching an ExecutionException to indicate "missing" and then manually populate the "missing keys" cache.  It feels quite awkward, especially the part where I throw an exception in the load method when there's no mapping.  So I wonder if there isn't a more elegant way to handle this kind of problem.

Comment: It feels unnatural, but I think (given all I learned) it is still the most flexible solution. Especially since you also can have different size/eviction settings and you get two statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something based on `refresh`, where you implement `CacheLoader.reload(key, oldValue)` to refresh the "missing" mapping aggressively and you just keep the `oldValue` if the `oldValue` isn't "missing."

Comment: Interesting idea.  So I would set refreshAfterWrite to the length that I wanted to cache missing values, and then abort the reload (by keeping the old value) if it's not missing.  My concern would be that I'd have a ton of spurious refreshes (albeit not really doing much), which could be a performance problem for the refresh thread.  I will test it out, see if I like it better than the 2 cache solution.

Comment: Also I just realized this will leave me unable to do "normal" refreshes of non-missing cache entries.  This is not a problem in this particular case, since the cached data can't change, but in other situations it could be a problem.

Comment: I have a similliar method. In my particular case the refresh() however would detect that an entry needs to be removed, and there seems to be not a method to do that in the CacheLoader.